# How to extract multiples pdfs from huge csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, file, pdf, huge-pages

Im beginning in Python and I have to extract multiples pdf files form a huge csv file. I tried chunk method to read CSV file data. With the code below, I could extract only one pdf file.
I have some doubts :

1. How I can Know the number of pdf files in this csv ?
2. How can I extract all of them ?

I ask for some help...

Thanks !!

I tried the code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    import inspect
    import pprint
    import pandas as module
    functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
    pprint.pprint(functions)
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from datetime import datetime
    import seaborn as sns

    import csv
    from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

    def getstuff(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    yield next(datareader)  # yield the header row
    # first row, plus any subsequent rows that match, then stop
    # reading altogether
    # Python 2: use `for row in takewhile(...): yield row` instead
    # instead of `yield from takewhile(...)`.
    #yield from takewhile(
        #lambda r: r[3] == criterion,
        #dropwhile(lambda r: r[3] != criterion, datareader))
    #return

    def getdata(filename):
        #for criterion in criteria:
            for row in getstuff(filename):
                yield row

    generator=getstuff('C:\\Users\saitosp\Desktop\InCor\CAT1I_ecg_x.csv')
    print(next(generator))
    print(next(generator))
    print(next(generator))
    print(next(generator))

    chunksize=500
    ecg=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\saitosp\Desktop\InCor\CAT1I_ecg_x.csv', chunksize=chunksize)

    list(ecg.get_chunk(1000))
    ecg.get_chunk(1000)
    df=ecg.get_chunk(1000)

    empty_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].isnull().all()]
    # Drop these columns from the dataframe
    df.drop(empty_cols,
    axis=1,
    inplace=True)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print(row['OBJECTID'], row['OBJECTTYPE'])

    def print_full(x):
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
        pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:20,.2f}'.format)
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        print(x)
        pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
        pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
        pd.reset_option('display.width')
        pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
        pd.reset_option('display.max_colwidth')

    print_full(df.iloc[0]["OBJECTDATA"])
    b64=df.iloc[0]["OBJECTDATA"]
    from base64 import b64decode
    bytes = b64decode(b64, validate=True)
    # Write the PDF contents to a local file
    f = open('file.pdf', 'wb')
    f.write(bytes)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Hi there! So why not use the code you posted? Where is the problem with it?

Comment: Not sure understand. How could a PDF be stored in a CSV? Do you have an example please?